# stochastic calculus confusion

Tags: stochastic-processes, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-integrals

Let $I_t$ be your investment(in number of units) in a stock at time t and it depends on the value of the stock S in the following way:

$I_t = f(S_t)$

In this case, change in your wealth during an infinitesimal interval would be given by:

$dX_t = f(S_t)dS_t$

If $S_t$ is deterministic and non-stochastic:

$X_T − X_0 = \int_{S_0}^{S_T} f(S_t) dS_t$

$= F(S_T)-F(S_0)$

where

$ F(S) = \int_a^S f(x)dx  .$   for whatever a is chosen

If however, $S_t$ is stochastic with

$dS_t = S_t  × (μ_t dt + σ_t dW_t)$

then

$X_T − X_0 = F(S_T)-F(S_0) −0.5 \int_0^T f'(S_t) S_t^2 σ_t^2 dt$

My confusion is regarding the second part when S is stochastic. Is there a way to prove the stochastic case?

Comment: what do you mean by "would the integral be definite"?

Comment: sorry just meant non stochastic, i have edited

Comment: I deleted my answer cause I realized I didn't actually know where you were getting the last equation from and didn't want to assume it was wrong. But, be assured that $X_t = f(S_t)$ does not imply $dX_t = f(S_t)dS_t.$ It implies (Ito's lemma) that $$dX = f'(S)dS + \frac{1}{2}f''(S)\sigma^2 S^2 dt$$ (provided we have $dS = \mu Sdt + \sigma S dS.$) (And also be assured that regardless of its origin and correctness, the last expression you wrote is random, not deterministic.)

Comment: Ok let me give a little more context here, I'll quickly edit further. Thanks for your comments though- they are helpful.

Comment: Yes, that makes much more sense now. By "prove the stochastic case" did you mean derive that formula? If so, see answer below.

Comment: perfect, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression comes from Ito's lemma. Let $F(S) = \int_a^S f(x)dx$ so that $F'(S) = f(S).$ Then if $dS = \mu S dt + \sigma S dS,$ and we let $Y_t=F(S_t),$ Ito's lemma gives $$ dY = F'(S)dS + \frac{1}{2}F''(S)\sigma^2 S^2dt \\= f(S)dS + \frac{1}{2}f'(S)\sigma^2S^2dt\\= dX + \frac{1}{2}f'(S)\sigma^2S^2 dt.$$

Integrating gives $$Y_T-Y_0 = X_T-X_0 +\frac{1}{2}\int_0^T f'(S_t)\sigma^2 S_t^2 dt.$$ Plugging in $Y_T-Y_0 = F(S_T)-F(S_0)$ and rearranging gives your expression.